# RVM --default bug

Tags: ruby, rvm

I set the default ruby as,

```
rvm --default 1.9.2
```

when I do `ruby -v`, I get 'ruby 1.9.1'

when I do `which ruby` I get `.rvm/rubies/1.9.2PathOfRuby`

Any idea how to fix this?

When I run a sample program, printing the version of ruby i.e, `print RUBY_VERSION` it prints 1.9.1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using rvm along with a default ruby of 1.9.2 v0:

```
Greg:~ greg$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]

Greg:~ greg$ rvm -v

rvm 0.1.46 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Greg:~ greg$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
Greg:~ greg$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
```

I'm not sure what the current version of rvm is, but 0.1.46 seems to be working correctly. You might want to try doing `rvm update` to get the latest rev if you're running an older version.

Your best solution for rvm help is to go directly to the author, Wayne Seguin, either on the RVM site or on #IRC at irc.freenode.net. The RVM site is http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/.

Wayne's a great guy, very helpful and quick to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH statement in .bash_profile (or equivalent). Remove entries that reference gems/ruby-1.9.1-yadda. Restart your terminal and check the version of ruby then. It should report 1.9.2 now, although you might need to rerun `rvm 1.9.2 --default` again.